# get part of a Tree Structure in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, hierarchy

I have the tree stucture of the departments of a company.
The link for the Parent-Child department in the table is: 
Departments.ID->Departments.parentID.
However I don't need the whole tree. 
The thing is that the structure of the departments has changed during the years and I would like to keep only a part of the tree.
For example:

```
-Root
--Parent 1
---Child 01
---Child 02
--Parent 2
---Child 01
---Child 02 (This is the parent that I want to have in my "shorter" tree
----Child 001 (This is the part of the tree that I want. The depth is more than 1)
---Child 04
--Parent 03
```

Can I say something like "get me everything under `Child 001`"?
Does this even makes sense?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you using the `File System Data` connection?

Answer (score 0):

I think I rushed and ask the question.
While I was adding tables and data for my report the tree gets "shorter" because of database fields that are null. So when I added all the tables that I wanted to use, the "older" departments disapear because of the NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `File System Data` connection, add this to your record-selection formula:

```
{x.Directory}="Root\Parent 2\Child 02
OR {x.Parent Directory} LIKE "Root\Parent 2\Child 02*"
```

You could also choose to set the database 'table' to the desired parent node.